# calculate Cassandra token from row key using PHP

Tags: php, cassandra, md5

How can I calculate Cassandra token corresponding to some row key using PHP

"they" say this is MD5, converted in decimal, 
however what I am calculating, not seems to be correct token.

```
//this is one of the ways i tried,
number_format(hexdec( md5($key ) ), 0, '', '')

//this is second:
md5_hex_to_dec( md5($key) );


function md5_hex_to_dec($hex_str)
{
    // here i experimented with higher bit.
    $c = $hex_str[0];
    $c1 = hexdec($c);
    if ($c1 > 7)
                $c1 = $c1 - 7;
    // --- eo ----
    $hex_str[0] = dechex($c1);
    $arr = str_split($hex_str, 4);
    foreach ($arr as $grp) {
        $dec[] = str_pad(hexdec($grp), 5, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
    }
    return implode('', $dec);
}
```

Comment: PHP has the md5() function... what are you doing now? What does "in decimal" mean? Do you have an example of a correct Cassandra token?

Comment: here, i updated the question.
I am trying to extend PHP Cassa, not sure what is correct token (will need to try with java later), but result I got is incorrect for sure.

Comment: It would help a lot if you posted example input and output, so we can see what results you are getting, and what you think they ought to be...

Comment: this is something difficult to do in test environment. the token is very large integer for example I know "696a" and "696a" must be numbers smaller than 21267647932558653966460912964485513216 but quite close to it.

Comment: the both algorithms give bigger number, e.g. "696a" is equal to
320871726326306902437151799895908155392
or
3312542375546300071345864227911525757799,
that is bigger than 21267647932558653966460912964485513216

Answer (score 0):

Each cassandra node has a token which represents the RANGE of hashes that it will store.  ie. To calculate the token from the rowkey you

1. get the hash
2. know all the tokens in the ring and figure out which range it belongs to(ie. find which range and find the start token for that range).

ie. once you md5 hash it, you have to map that to the token that is less than that hash.

Dean

Comment: Generally, when you insert a new row, Cassandra calculates a token. By this token it decide where to put it.

Most common use for this is to develop token aware client, e.g. this client send the query to the node where key is stored. This then minimize the 'proxy' connections between nodes.

Comment: true, so it must be something like the above....you can probably look at the java astyanax code or java hector code to figure it out though.